# I need php regular expression to allow the all leters, numbers, dollar sign, commas, double & single quotes

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that allows:

```
(A-Za-z) all letters,
(0-9) all numbers,
($) dollar sign, 
(,) commas
(") & (') double and single quotes
```

so far i have - `'/[^a-zA-Z0-9,_ %\[$,\]\.\(\)%&-]/s'`

the idea is to strip out all special characters

/^[a-zA-Z0-9$,"']+$/

This does not work for some reason it is allowing special characters to show which are not supported by the page encoding. - bit.ly/GDIYC9 I need to use the regex i posted to remove special characters and only allow the characters I explained before. thanks

thanks

Comment: What's wrong with it? What should and shouldn't it match? Examples?

Comment: And you say you want to allow letters, but your expression says `[^a-zA-Z` - starting a character set with `^` is a negation

Comment: are you trying to find illegal characters created from a file encoding issue?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than stripping all special characters, you can simply match the required character, and that would be smaller regex.

You can use this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9$,"']+$/
```

Comment: +1 Whitelist, don't blacklist!

Comment: This does not work for some reason it is allowing special characters to show which are not supported by the page encoding. - http://bit.ly/GDIYC9

I need to use the regex i posted to remove special characters and only allow the characters I explained before. thanks